# About mailing list software or something like that

Tags: mailing-lists

Is there any mailing list or mailing software that could handle this kind scenario:

If I join to mailing list at week 4, mailing system starts sending me emails starting from number 1. Next week, on week 5 my friend joins to mailing list too, and the mailing system starts sending emails to him, starting from number 1 too. If another people joins to mailing list on week 5 too, he also starts receiving mails starting from number 1. And this continues weekly until everyone on this list has received all, let's say, 35 emails.

Comment: Ah, you're trying to produce a weekly serial of some sort! Cool!

Comment: Yes, some kind of. Everyone joining could get same series starting from number 1, no matter when they join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common way to do this is with a service like [AWeber](http://www.aweber.com/), using their [autoresponders](http://www.aweber.com/autoresponders.htm) & followups.

I took a look at ProBlogger, and yep, based on the `form` tag on his [signup page](http://www.problogger.net/31-days-to-build-a-better-blog-join-9100-other-bloggers-today/), he's using AWeber.

Comment: This seems to do exactly what I wanted. But I would like to find an open source alternative (and a desktop one, if possible)

Answer (score 0):

[Darren Rowse of ProBlogger](http://www.problogger.net/about-problogger/) does this with his [31 Days to Building a Better Blog](http://www.problogger.net/archives/category/31-days-to-building-a-better-blog/) series,
you might want to send him a mail to ask how he does that.

But my guess is that in most cases this is an own written mailing list and a scheduled task to send mails.

It also depends on how you want people to sign-up... By mail? By an online form?